# transpose pandas columns with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['Male','Male','Male','Male','Female','Female','Female','Female','Male','Male','Male','Male','Female','Female','Female','Female'],
                'Year' :[2008,2008,2009,2009,2008,2008,2009,2009,2008,2008,2009,2009,2008,2008,2009,2009],
           'rate':[2.3,3.2,4.5,6.7,5.6,3.2,3.5,2.6,2.3,3.2,4.5,6.7,5.6,3.2,3.5,2.6],
           'Heading':['TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123','TNMAB123',
                     'TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456','TNMAB456'],
           'target':[31.2,33.4,33.4,35.2,35.2,36.4,36.4,37.2,31.2,33.4,33.4,35.2,35.2,36.4,36.4,37.2],
            'day_type':['wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend','wk','wkend']})
```

As you can see there are duplicate values in all columns.

I would like to transpose/pivot them to get an output as shown below. Though I tried the below it didn't work.

```
df1.pivot(index='Year', columns='Heading', values='rate')
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below where each year is made as a row and all the corresponding entries for that year are made as columns.

Please note I haven't filled in the values as table column structure is more important.

[image]

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. You can use [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) here and convert the Multi-Index to single level index using [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=['Year','Gender'],columns='Heading',values='rate').unstack()

df1.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in df1.columns.tolist()]

df1 
      TDAS3_Female  TDAS3_Male  TNMAB123_Female  TNMAB123_Male  TSAD4_Female  TSAD4_Male  TWQE2_Female  TWQE2_Male
Year
2008           NaN         NaN              6.3            2.3           NaN         NaN           NaN         NaN
2009           NaN         NaN              7.1            3.2           NaN         NaN           2.1         4.5
2010           5.3         5.6              NaN            NaN           NaN         NaN           4.2         6.7
2011           3.6         3.2              NaN            NaN           2.9         3.5           NaN         NaN
2012           NaN         NaN              NaN            NaN           6.2         2.6           NaN         NaN
```

---

There are couple of ways to convert Multi-Index to single level. Using [`df.colums`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) or [`df.columns.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html) or [`pd.MultiIndex.to_flat_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html)

- `['_'.join(i) for i in df1.columns.tolist()]`
- `['_'.join(i) for i in df1.columns]`
- `['_'.join(i) for i in df1.columns.to_flat_index()]`

Comment: @TheGreat Glad to help. ;) `df1.pivot_table(index=['Year','Gender'],columns='Heading').unstack();df1.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in df.columns.tolist()]` this will create columns with rate and target.

Comment: @TheGreat You forgot to assign output. `df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=['Year','Gender'],columns='Heading',values='rate').unstack()`

Comment: Okay, I guess there was a typo in your answer `df` instead of `df1`.

Comment: @TheGreat Yes my bad :P, Fixed it.

Comment: Actually I guess there is minor problem. When I have 3 columns, it doesn't work correctly. Updating the sample dataframe to reprduce

Comment: @TheGreat Update with sample dataframe and expected output.

Comment: @ChesteR - Updated the post with sample dataframe